# If $X$ is an irreducible variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$ is path-connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

**My question**: Prove that if $X$ is an irreducible variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$ is path-connected in the standard metric topology.

For every two distinct points $p,q$ in $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$,let $L$ denote the line through $p$ and $q$. I can prove the line is a continuous path but I don't know how to show $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$ i.e. how to use the condition that $X$ is irreducible?

I'm stuck on this question for several hours. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Think about the *complex* line $\{tp+(1-t)q\in\mathbb{C}^n\mid t\in\mathbb{C}\}\cong\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I still don't get it.....I can see the isomorphism but how should I use it? Can you help a little bit more?

Comment: Bigger hint: What is the intersection of $X$ with this line?

Comment: I'm confused....$X$ is just an arbitrary irreducible variety and $L$ is the line through $p$ and $q$. We don't have specific "data" about them, how do we even know $X \cap L$?

Comment: Put it another way, what can you say about the intersection?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to assume $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$ does not hold. Then we have $L \cap X \neq \emptyset$ and I need to show it would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: No, there are no reasons for $L\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n-X$ (e.g., $X$ a hyperplane).  What can you say about $X\cap L\subset L\cong\mathbb{C}$ and $\#(X\cap L)$?

Comment: wait, so we don't need to prove $L \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$? Why? A space is path-connected if for every two points we can find a continuous path which is lying inside the space to connect them. In this case, the path for every two point the the line through them and I know how to prove it is continuous. I thought it remains to prove every such line is inside the space i.e. $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$. Did I misunderstood the definition of path-connectedness?

Comment: $L$ is the *complex* line through $p,q$.  It doesn't need to be entirely contained in $\mathbb{C}^n-X$ for there to be a path $[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}^n-X$ joining $p,q$.

Comment: I kind of get what you mean. Let $V=\mathbb{C}^n \setminus X$. If we can show $L \cap V$ is path-connected, then the line segment connecting $p$ and $q$ is in $L \cap V \subseteq V$ for every such pair of points $p,q$. So I guess we need to use $L \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $|L \cap X|=?$ to show $L \cap V$ is path-connected?

Comment: But how do we get the cardinality of $L \cap X$?

Comment: What do you know about $X$?  So what do you know about $L\cap X$?

Comment: If we write $X=V(S)$ for some $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $X \subseteq V(f)$ for some non-zero $f \in S$. So $X$ is finite. Hence $L \cap X$ is also finite? But I didn't use the condition that $X$ is irreducible...What did I do wrong?

Comment: $X$ need not be finite, but $L\cap X$ is finite since it is an algebraic set and can't be $L$.  Irreducibility doesn't come in here, the result is true for all algebraic sets $X$.

Comment: I can see $L \cap X$ is an algebraic set and $L \cap X$ can't be $L$, but I don't see how does this imply $L \cap X$ is finite. Is it because $L \cong \mathbb{C}$? Since $L \cap X$ is a proper subvariety of $L$ and $L \cong \mathbb{C}$, so $L \cap X=\emptyset$ or a finite set. If it is empty, then we are done. If not, then it is finite.

Comment: Yes, we are using $L\cong\mathbb{C}$ to deduce $L\cap X$ finite.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and the step-by-step guidance!